# NetfilterQueue set_payload keeps the original payload

Tags: python, tcp, scapy, bridge

So I am trying to create sort of a MitM setup to alter the content of TCP (HTTP) packets.
I current have a Linux bridge that looks as follows:

IoT Device ---(eth)---- Laptop ----(usb)---- 3G Modem

The bridge is setup using the normal Linux procedure (i.e., ip link) and up to now everything is working fine and the bridge is transparent for both ends.

Next, I forwarded all packets to the NFQueue:
`iptables -A FORWARD -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 0`

and parse them with Python:
In Python 3

```
def print_and_accept(pkt):
    print(pkt)
    http_packet = scapy.IP(pkt.get_payload())

    if http_packet.haslayer(scapy.Raw) and http_packet.haslayer(TCP):
        if http_packet[TCP].dport == 80 or http_packet[TCP].sport == 80:
            http_packet[TCP].payload = scapy.Raw(http_packet[TCP].payload.load.decode().replace("text","txet"))
            print(http_packet[TCP].payload)
            del http_packet[IP].chksum, http_packet[TCP].chksum

            pkt.set_payload(bytes(http_packet))
            print('>> Payload Changed')
    pkt.accept()


nfqueue = NetfilterQueue()
nfqueue.bind(0, print_and_accept)
try:
    nfqueue.run()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('exiting')

nfqueue.unbind()
```

In Python 2 one can do the same but then use `pkt.set_verdict_modified(nfqueue.NF_ACCEPT, str(http_packet), len(http_packet))` at the end.

However, when inspecting packets via Wireshark (captured on the bridge), I still see the original payload. I already tried many, many proposed solutions but nothing seems to work.

PS: If I use the workaround of `drop()` and `send()` via scapy, I don't even see the packet in Wireshark.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: For anyone looking for the answer, it seems that I was capturing the new (modified) packets on the wrong interface with Wireshark. Just change the interface and Voila.